# Accounting for imbalance in number of time points per observation to estimate average treatment effect

Tags: causality, treatment-effect

This is a follow up to [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/460480/guidelines-for-comparing-treatments-when-some-patients-receive-different-number/460484?noredirect=1#comment854944_460484) question. How can someone estimate the Average treatment effect (ATE) when not every observation has the same number of treatments/exposures? This is not dropout because the patients received the number of treatments deemed necessary. How could someone estimate the ATE in these cases?

Comment: Aside the notion of sequential treatments suggested in Noah's answer in the linked question, you might want to explore the notion of "matching with doses". A seminal reference on that is Lu et al. (2001) [Matching With Doses in an Observational Study of a Media Campaign Against Drug Abuse](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4267480/); Yang et al. (2016) [Propensity Score Matching and Subclassification in Studies with Multi-level Treatments](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1111/biom.12505) offers a more update take on the matter.

Comment: These are all slightly different implementations though right? for the doses paper this is a point treatment design and every patient is able to be put into groups at each time point in the generalized propesity score paper. In my case some patients are a point treatment study while others have a longitudinal nature

Comment: Yes, agreed. I mostly thought of it as the patients "accruing" treatments.